# Not able to install .Net core in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, .net-core

Linux is totally new to me. i am trying to install .Net Core in ubuntu 14.05.

I try following command to install ubuntu

```
  sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
  /repos/dotnet-release/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d  
  /dotnetdev.list'

    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 
     417A0893

    sudo apt-get update
```

These command run successfully when i run below command i got error

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003131
```

My error is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview1-002702
```

Comment: have you removed previous version of .NET Core? https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/uninstall/dotnet-uninstall-debian-packages.sh Also this post may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/783897/ubuntu-unable-to-install-net-core

Comment: This is totally new machine. no previous version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. It seems like .NET Core don't support 32-bit Ubuntu. I changed to 64-bit Ubuntu, the problem is solved.