# Is Installing .net core on 32bit ubuntu possible?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

Ubuntu OS

```
root@anil-ubuntu:/ms# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

[MS Docs](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu), I am following, says.

**Install .NET Core SDK**

To install .NET Core 1.1 on Ubuntu or Linux Mint, simply use apt-get.

.NET Core 1.1 is the latest version. For long term support versions and additional downloads [check the all Linux downloads section](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux).

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

On executing apt-get, getting failed msg.

```
root@anil-ubuntu:/ms# sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.1'
```

I referred this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072713/not-able-to-install-net-core-in-ubuntu-14-04), checked OS, it is 32bit.

```
root@anil-ubuntu:/ms# uname -a
Linux anil-ubuntu 4.4.0-72-generic #93~14.04.1-Ubuntu
 SMP Fri Mar 31 15:06:30 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I am a Windows developer and new to Ubuntu. 
Here problem to my solution seems to be to [upgrade to 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation). 
Want to ensure from experts will it not be a risk to upgrade my Ubuntu development system where I also have an active Perl project and its various CPAN modules installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET Core 1.x does not support 32bit Ubuntu. Also, there are no plans to add this for .NET Core 2.0. See [the .Net Core roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md) for a full list of supported platforms.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), which is a port of some .NET components to Linux.

Comment: Is .net core(s) not next version of Mono?

Comment: Oh, perhaps. My knowledge could well be out of date. I haven't looked at Mono for many years.

Comment: Mono and .NET Core are separate projects. Neither is a continuation or upgraded version of the other. You can actually use both side by side on Linux.

Comment: yes but core is advance then mono and it is by Microsoft and serves the same purpose.

Comment: @Anil Both Mono and .Net Core support .Net Standard, so neither is more advanced in terms of APIs. And since Microsoft bough Xamarin, Mono is also made by Microsoft. If you want to develop web applications on Linux, .Net Core is the better choice, but if you want something else, Mono might make sense.